# WebSocket proxying with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am confused by the nginx documentation for web socket proxying.

From the documentation here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

> A more sophisticated example in which a value of the “Connection”
>   header field in a request to the proxied server depends on the
>   presence of the “Upgrade” field in the client request header:
>
> ```
> http {
>     map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
>         default upgrade;
>         ''      close;
>     }
>
>     server {
>         ...
>
>         location /chat/ {
>             proxy_pass http://backend;
>             proxy_http_version 1.1;
>             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
>         }
>     }
> ```

I want something similar in that I want to pass the upgrade in the connection if the Upgrade header is preset, otherwise I want to do the equivalent of `proxy_set_header Connection ""`.

I think the example in the documentation is doing `proxy_set_header Connection close` if there is no Upgrade header? If so how do I modified the `map` to do what I want. It seems like I need to do `proxy_set_header Connection ""` as

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
   default upgrade;
   ''      '';
}
```

but something doesn't feel right about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
   default upgrade;
   ''      '';
}
```

does indeed do what I want.